# Retrieve users from specific group and OU in Active Dirctory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to retrieve all users in a given group from specific OU in Active Directory. My code throws an exception

> The operation was aborted because the client side timeout limit was exceeded

I get this exception at

```
foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in searchResponse.Entries)
```

My group name is `Arya` and OU name is `TestOU`

However when I write my filter as

```
string searchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=user)"
```

it works and returns users from all OU's, I think which I do not want.

```
bool bMoreData = false;

DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);
string[] attributes = { "samaccountname", "displayname", "name", "initials" };

System.Net.NetworkCredential credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(admin, password, "IP address");

LdapDirectoryIdentifier directoryIdentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("ip address"); //389 (unsecured LDAP)
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(directoryIdentifier, credential);
connection.Bind();

string searchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=cn=Arya,ou=TestOU,dc=Maintenance,dc=org))";
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("DC=Maintenance,DC=org", searchFilter, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Base, attributes);
// getCookie();

DirSyncRequestControl dirSyncRC = new DirSyncRequestControl(cookie, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectorySynchronizationOptions.IncrementalValues, Int32.MaxValue);
request.Controls.Add(dirSyncRC);

SearchResponse searchResponse = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);

foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in searchResponse.Entries)// Exception thrown here
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",
    searchResponse.Entries.IndexOf(entry),
    entry.DistinguishedName);
}

foreach (DirectoryControl control in searchResponse.Controls)
{
    if (control is DirSyncResponseControl)
    {
        DirSyncResponseControl dsrc = control as DirSyncResponseControl;
        cookie = dsrc.Cookie;
        bMoreData = dsrc.MoreData;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using this very low-level LDAP interface??

Comment: I have a local database which I need to sync up with AD server, above api create cookie, so that it won't fetch the record next which is not been modified. I found above solution and moved with that. I want to achieve this using filter

Answer (score 1):

I found problem with the below line

```
DirSyncRequestControl dirSyncRC = new DirSyncRequestControl(cookie, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectorySynchronizationOptions.IncrementalValues, Int32.MaxValue);
```

when replaced it with it worked for me.

```
DirSyncRequestControl dirSyncRC = new DirSyncRequestControl(cookie, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectorySynchronizationOptions.ObjectSecurity, Int32.MaxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to a `PrincipalContext` for your OU, and then find that group you're looking for:

```
// create your domain context - bind to the OU you're interested in
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, "OU=TestOU"))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for any GroupPrincipal 
   GroupPrincipal group = ctx.FindByIdentity("Arya");

   // if group is found - enumerate its members
   if(group != null) 
   {
       foreach(var found in group.GetMembers())
       {
            // 
       }
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineJanuary2008en-us.chm) (downloadable `.CHM` file from Microsoft - January 2008 issue of MSDN Magazine) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.